# Saving a dynamic API response into DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm nearly done with my ecommerce site that I've hacked together.  After getting rates from different shippers, I formatted them into a select form as such

I'm using the active_shipping gem to get the rates

```
  <select name="shipping option">
        <option>
        </option>
    <% @order_preview.fedex_rates.each do |rate| %>
        <option>
        <%= rate.service_name %>
        <%= number_to_currency(rate.price.to_f / 100) %>
        </option>
    <% end %>
        <option>
        </option>
    <% @order_preview.usps_rates.each do |rate| %>
        <option>
        <%= rate.service_name %>
        <%= number_to_currency(rate.price.to_f / 100) %>
        </option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
```

This way each iteration creates it's own option row.  The tricky part for me is having the selected option actually capture the information in the row.  The response includes a price, so I can't just save them into my DB because they are dynamic depending on package destination.

The response hash looks like this

```
<ActiveMerchant::Shipping::RateEstimate:0x00000101431c58 @service_name="FedEx Standard Overnight", @carrier="FedEx", @destination=4G
Brooklyn, NY, 11249
United States, @origin=Brooklyn, NY, 11249
United States, @service_code="STANDARD_OVERNIGHT", @package_rates=[{:package=>#<ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Package:0x000001049b9b78 @options={:cylinder=>nil, :units=>:imperial}, @dimensions=[#<Quantified::Length: 10.0 inches>, #<Quantified::Length: 10.0 inches>, #<Quantified::Length: 10.0 inches>], @weight_unit_system=:imperial, @dimensions_unit_system=:imperial, @weight=#<Quantified::Mass: 10.0 ounces>, @value=nil, @currency=nil, @cylinder=false, @gift=false, @oversized=false, @unpackaged=false, @inches=[10.0, 10.0, 10.0]>}], @total_price=3378, @negotiated_rate=nil, @currency="USD", @delivery_range=[Tue, 27 May 2014 00:00:00 +0000, Tue, 27 May 2014 00:00:00 +0000], @shipping_date=nil, @delivery_date=Tue, 27 May 2014 00:00:00 +0000, @insurance_price=nil>, #<ActiveMerchant::Shipping::RateEstimate:0x0000010404e2f0 @service_name="FedEx Priority Overnight", @carrier="FedEx", @destination=4G
Brooklyn, NY, 11249
United States, @origin=Brooklyn, NY, 11249
United States, @service_code="PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT", @package_rates=[{:package=>#<ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Package:0x000001049b9b78 @options={:cylinder=>nil, :units=>:imperial}, @dimensions=[#<Quantified::Length: 10.0 inches>, #<Quantified::Length: 10.0 inches>, #<Quantified::Length: 10.0 inches>], @weight_unit_system=:imperial, @dimensions_unit_system=:imperial, @weight=#<Quantified::Mass: 10.0 ounces>, @value=nil, @currency=nil, @cylinder=false, @gift=false, @oversized=false, @unpackaged=false, @inches=[10.0, 10.0, 10.0]>}], @total_price=4418, @negotiated_rate=nil, @currency="USD", @delivery_range=[Tue, 27 May 2014 00:00:00 +0000, Tue, 27 May 2014 00:00:00 +0000], @shipping_date=nil, @delivery_date=Tue, 27 May 2014 00:00:00 +0000, @insurance_price=nil>, #<ActiveMerchant::Shipping::RateEstimate:0x0000010a405e88 @service_name="FedEx Priority Overnight Saturday Delivery", @carrier="FedEx", @destination=4G
Brooklyn, NY, 11249
United States, @origin=Brooklyn, NY, 11249
United States, @service_code="PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT", @package_rates=[{:package=>#<ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Package:0x000001049b9b78 @options={:cylinder=>nil, :units=>:imperial}, @dimensions=[#<Quantified::Length: 10.0 inches>, #<Quantified::Length: 10.0 inches>, #<Quantified::Length: 10.0 inches>], @weight_unit_system=:imperial, @dimensions_unit_system=:imperial, @weight=#<Quantified::Mass: 10.0 ounces>, @value=nil, @currency=nil, @cylinder=false, @gift=false, @oversized=false, @unpackaged=false, @inches=[10.0, 10.0, 10.0]>}], @total_price=6170, @negotiated_rate=nil, @currency="USD", @delivery_range=[Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00 +0000, Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00 +0000], @shipping_date=nil, @delivery_date=Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00 +0000, @insurance_price=nil>
```

Would it be good practice to save the @service_code titles into a DB and then match them to the API call only to populate the field if it matches one that is in my DB (that way I could also solve my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819668/active-shipping-limit-responses-to-certain-shipping-methods).)

Let me know what would be advised.  This is my first ecom dev job!
Thanks a lot!  Pat